# Can Directory Searcher Query Operational Attributes?

Tags: c#, .net, ldap, directorysearcher

I'm using the .net directory searcher to query data from OpenLDAP. It connects OK and I can query the user data, but operational attributes don't seem to be returned. This is a problem, as I need the entryUUID. I've tried adding "entryUUID" to the propertiesToLoad parameter when constructing the DirectorySearcher, and have also tried "+" (which according to the OpenLDAP documentation should return all operational attributes), but no joy.

Does anyone have any suggestions please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find a way of doing this, so in the end I used the LDAPConnection class in the DirectoryServices.Protocols namespace instead. The DirectorySearcher class seems to be primarily designed for querying Active Directory - while it can query other LDAP Directories its functionality is limited.